# Tomcat 6.0.35 installation on Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, tomcat6, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install apache-tomcat-6.0.35 on Mac OS x 10.9, but I have this error in *catalina.out* when I run *startup.sh* :

```
/Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/catalina.sh: line 375: /Library/Java/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

And thus, the server isn't launched.

Here is what I get in terminal (bash) :

```
myMac:bin administrator$ ./startup.sh

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat/Home
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat/Home
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/Home/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/bootstrap.jar
```

Any advice?

Comment: As in the error message, it cannot find Java on your machine, define `JAVA_HOME` in `catalina.sh` file like `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java`

Comment: <<export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export CATALINA_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/Home   >>> is entered in .profile file

Answer (score 4):

It seems the issue is related to your JAVA_HOME environment variable. Check to see if it is correctly set. To verify, run
    `javac -version` or `which java`
on the command line to see which version of java is set and is the correct one that should be used.

Comment: which version of the jdk should we download. when i ran the above command <servpro41:~ administrator$ javac -version
No Java runtime present, requesting install. >    and when we ran "which java" we get <servpro41:~ administrator$ which java
/usr/bin/java>.

Comment: It means that you don't have the JDK installed at all. You will need to download and install it and export JAVA_HOME in your path to get it working. You require JDK (not the JRE).

Comment: Any specific versions of the JDK which goes with tomcat 6.0.35

Comment: Tomcat6 supports JDK version 5 and later

Comment: Installed JDK   <<servpro41:~ administrator$ javac -version
                  javac 1.8.0_05>>

Comment: Still the catalina.out gives the same /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/./catalina.sh: line 375: /Library/Java/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: is the JAVA_HOME variable set ? you need to set that as well besides installing the JDK

Comment: How to set the variable?

Comment: Its as simple as running the command `export JAVA_HOME=$(/path/to/java)` For more explanation, take a look into this [post_here] (http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: we have already created a .profile file <<<<<                 export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export CATALINA_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/Home

Comment: Have you also re-executed it by `source .bash_profile` ? If that doesn't work, try to log out of all terminal sessions and log back in and then try it out

Comment: vim .bash_profile 
 
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
 
$ source .bash_profile
 
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home  >>>>is this what we have to run in the terminal to set JAVA_HOME

Comment: Yes that is correct. Ofcourse you will have to replace `/usr/libexec/java_home` with your path to java home

Comment: vim .bash_profile  gives error<<<E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".bash_profile.swp">>

Comment: We deleted the file. what will be my java path...whether it is /Library/Java/Home   or the command which java gives /usr/bin/java

Comment: :~ administrator$ vim .bash_profile
:~ administrator$ source .bash_profile
:~ administrator$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
:~ administrator$ cd /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin
:bin administrator$ chmod u+x *.sh
:bin administrator$ /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat/Home
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat/Home
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/Home/temp
Using JRE_HOME:      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:     /Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/bootstrap.jar

Comment: In the catalina.out we have error>>org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/administrator/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.May 22, 2014 4:49:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 19 column 2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

Comment: I have not replaced the pat (/usr/libexec/java_home)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I've made it work under OS X 10.9, with Java 6 (1.6.0_37-b06-434).

As it was complaining about a wrong path in Java in the *catalina.out*, I changed all the paths to my JRM in *setclasspath.sh* :

Old path :

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current
```

New path :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home
```

There were 3 places affected :

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" -a -z "$JRE_HOME" ]; then
  # Bugzilla 37284 (reviewed).
  if $darwin; then
    if [ -d "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home" ]; then
      export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home"
    fi

[...]

# OSX hack to CLASSPATH
JIKESPATH=
if [ `uname -s` = "Darwin" ]; then
  OSXHACK="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk/Contents/Home"

[...]
```

As you can see, the code already export `JAVA_HOME`, so no need to export it in .bash_profile here.